# Rails: How to change integer to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a website database. For one of the columns, I used the item number code as an integer. Couldn't handle the number size so it would be better to make it as a string. But I already set it as an integer and I couldn't simply just change it in the code. How do I do this?

This is my migration file.

```
class CreateInventories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :inventories do |t|
      t.string :product_name
      t.string :brand_name
      t.integer :item_id
      t.integer :upc_code
      t.string :color
      t.string :department
      t.string :size
      t.string :condition
      t.string :fabric_type
      t.string :shipping_weight
      t.string :sku
      t.string :asin
      t.integer :quantity
      t.string :cost_price
      t.string :sell_price
      t.string :key_product_features
      t.text :product_description
      t.string :search_terms
      t.string :status
      t.string :listing_in_usa
      t.string :listing_in_canada
      t.string :listing_in_mexico

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I want to make both upc_code and item_id into strings. How do I start?

Ok, so in the new file my code is

```
class UpdateColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    change_table :inventories do |t|
      t.change :upc_code, :string

    end
  end
end
```

but I get an error

> ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError Migrations are pending. To resolve
>   this issue, run: bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Comment: Is this table a work in progress, or is it merged to master/deployed anywhere? You *very* rarely want to edit existing migrations, unless they only exist on your local machine.

Comment: run `rails db:migrate`. That's why you're getting the ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError

Comment: that's what I did, but I'm still getting an error

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't run `rails db:migrate` or `rake db:migrate`, then you can simply change the data types within the migration to the needed one:

```
...
t.string :upc_code
...
```

Although if `item_id` is the foreign key that makes a relationship between `Inventory` and `Item` then you can't change the type, they must match as both integers.

But in the other hand, if you already run the `db:migrate` command then you can create a new migration in order to change the type of those attributes:

Run:

```
$ rails generate migration update_columns
```

And then you edit the created file:

```
class UpdateColumns < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :inventories do |t|
      t.change :upc_code, :string
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Then `rails db:migrate` again.

Comment: do i include the  t.timestamps?

Comment: Just your specific attribute. Try first without the `item_id` attribute.

Comment: It says migrations are pending, so you need to run `rails db:migrate`, you can check the status of your migrations with `rails db:migrate:status`, run it before.

Comment: I did the status thing,  it says "down    20170526141742  Update column" but when i run rails db:migrate, still doesn't work

Comment: Which database are you using? Is there more than a migration file with the same name in your `db/migrate` folder?